# A web application to record and share audio files with an expiration date?

Tags: web-apps, audio

Similar to a [Pastebin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) with an expiry date, I would like to record and share an audio file that is automatically being deleted after the expiration date has been passed.

The use of the app should be for free (Freemium) if possible.